# ASP.NET libraries/assemblies/dlls for creating, concatenating, and splitting PDF files in shared hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a requirement for a project that is hosted in a shared hosting environment, so we're unable to install or register any custom .NET libraries/dlls/assemblies, etc.

Is there a component that is natively available in IIS 7 that will allow us to create, concatenate, and/or split PDF files?  Something like a Persits component, but that doesn't require any custom installation on the server?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to register assemblies (or libraries, or whatever you call them in ASP.NET--bit of a newbie, here) through code...?

Comment: You'll need a third party library like PdfSharp or iTextSharp.

Comment: You should be able to reference 3rd party DLLs which are local to your project, or in some way included in your deployment.  It's not necessary to register them on the server or in the GAC or install anything.  (If it is necessary, I wouldn't recommend using that library.  Doesn't sound very portable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install anything on the server. You can just add the DLL to your bin folder and everything will work fine. If you are using Visual Studio, just right click the project --> Add Reference and browse to select the .NET library that you will use.

As far as the library itself, I used iTextSharp long time ago and it does offer everything you need as far as splitting, combining and creating PDFs on the fly. [Here's the link to the library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

[Lots of examples on how to use the library here.](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examples.html)

[Link to PDFSharp library](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), as suggested by jrummell (thanks!)

Comment: iTextSharp is Java port. It works great, but it doesn't follow .NET library conventions so its a little awkward. PdfSharp is a younger library written from scratch in .NET so it felt better for me. But both do the mostly the same thing.